# displaying count acording to connection time and source

Tags: python

I am  trying to build my dataset of network recording for that I want to count all connections of a specific source in a specific minute and display the result in this form  :

```
Time                     Source            Number of Connections

2018-03-18 21:17:0        192.168.0.2            5

2018-03-18 21:18:00       192.168.0.2            1

2018-03-18 21:17:0        192.168.0.3            2

.....
```

I am using this code to do the count : 
    c

```
onnection_count = {} # dictionary that stores count of connections per minute
for s in source: 
    for x in edited_time :
if  x in connection_count :
    value = connection_count[x] 
    value = value + 1  
    connection_count[x] = value
else:
    connection_count[x] = 1
    new_count_df #count # date #source
```

but I don't know how to display it the way I want in fact I used this  :

```
for s in source:
for x in edited_time :
    new_count_df = (_time, source, connection_count)
```

but it doesn't display it the way I want.

Comment: Please edit your question and indent it properly.

Comment: Please tell us how do you want it displayed, all you are saying is that it does not come out right.

Comment: in the begiin I said how I wanted to be displayed : 

{I am trying to build my dataset of network recording for that I want to count all connections of a specific source in a specific minute and display the result in this form : }

Comment: Time                     Source            Number of Connections

2018-03-18 21:17:0        192.168.0.2            5

2018-03-18 21:18:00       192.168.0.2            1

2018-03-18 21:17:0        192.168.0.3            2

.....